# Returning base class from WCF call

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have two classes:

```
[KnownType(typeof(QueueInfo))]
public class InfoObject:IExtensibleDataObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData { get; set; }
}

public class QueueInfo: InfoObject
{

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public QueueState State { get; set; }

}
```

And a remoting call:

```
public InfoObject GetQueueInfo( int queueId){
    return MyQueues[queueId] //<--- Value is a QueueInfo object
}
```

The base class is strictly for anonymous users and they arent allowed to view all the information.  Is it possible to return an InfoObject without serializing the QueueInfo properties, or must I make a new InfoObject and return that?

Comment: If you want is hide some information in the service just remove `[DataMember]` from the properties you don't want you client see. It will be applied to all clients.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when whatever type of object it is is received by the client of the WCF service, it will be deserialised as an object of whatever type is the return of the WCF method called. If the difference between the two types is in extra logic, and the data in the object is the same, the client can convert the returned object into an instance of the other type; if the data is different, it can't - it's missing some data necessary to the intended type.

You need to have separate calls for Authenticated and non-Authenticated users which return the different types.

Comment: But thats just it, its not returning the method's call type.  Its returning QueueInfo to the client, properties and all.  I need it to return just the base class, with no extra properties.

Comment: Can you post the methods signature? Wiat a minute; you have.

Comment: I did, its in the OP, towards the bottom.

Comment: GetQueueInfo is a method called by non authenticated users.

Comment: Is it returning am InfoObject which can be cast to a QueueInfo? What are you actually returning on the WCF side?

Comment: I want it to return just an InfoObject.  Not the properties of the derived type QueueInfo.

Comment: I see what's happening. You're actuallt returning QueueInfo objects, which can pass for InfoObjects. The client knows about about both, and deserialises them as QueueInfo objects. In your GetQueueInfo method, you need to convert to an InfoObject before returning, like so: return MyQueues[queueId] as QueueInfo;

Comment: That was my first thought, but it still returned the QueueInfo properties.

Comment: In that case, do a proper conversion from QueueInfo to InfoObject before returning (return a new InfoObject() with props copied from the QueueInfo). WCF is being clever here....

Answer (score 0):

If you checked the option "Reuse types in referenced assemblies", I think you can customize the serialization behavior of your extended class and omit that information so that the base properties arrive empty on the other side.